# sudo apt install gcc not working

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, gcc

I already tried this [Unable to install GCC, depends gcc-7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089719/unable-to-install-gcc-depends-gcc-7)

It did not work.

Here is what I get

```
$ sudo apt install gcc

**Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc : Depends: gcc-7 (>= 7.3.0-12~) but it is not going to be installed
*E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.**
```

Even `sudo apt install build-essential` is not working.

My Ubuntu version is 18.04.4.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu **version** (ex. `lsb_release -r`)? did you remember to run `sudo apt update` first?

Comment: @steeldriver done that already it didn't work.My Ubuntu version is 18.04.4.